# Groovy Cannot set readonly property: class for class

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to create object using map in constructor. The class is :

```
class Test implements Serializable {
    long id
    String name
}
```

The code block that fails:

```
Map testMap = [id: 1, name: "Test 1"]
Test test = new Test(testMap)
```

And I get exception like: `Cannot set readonly property: class for class.`
What is wrong with this code.

Comment: For me it works fine. Are you sure that the error comes from these two lines?

Comment: Yes. I debug the application over and over. Pointer goes to catch after this line. -_-

Comment: Sure your map doesn't have a key `class` in it?

Comment: yup. found it. `class` key was the culprit. Thanks.